# Add textbox to telerik radgrid confirmation dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I need to collect additional information from the user when they initiate a delete on a radgrid. Right now I am presenting the user with a confirmation dialog box that lets them click "OK" to continue but I need to add an additional textbox to collect a reason.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdconfirmationdialogs.html

Looks like you'll need to do a custom confirm dialog (possibly with a jQueryUI modal?) to add that form field in there.

Additionally, check this documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdaddingdeleteprompt.html

Specifically look at the heading "Display confirmation dialog with text including column cell value."  They are talking about having the confirm show a value from the RadGrid, but you could modify that technique to do your custom confirm box.